# Passing global variable to array

Tags: php, wordpress, global-variables, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to pass a global variable to gravity forms post submission function. So far everything comes back fine, but the global variable.

Here is where I am declaring the global in another function (I've stripped out some other bits for clarity):

```
$gid = null;
function things() {
  $jsondata = file_get_contents('http://urltoothers.com');
  $json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
  global $gid;
  $gid = $json['id_of_json_thing'];
}
```

This is what I have in my other function:

```
global $gid;
$body = array(
    'name' => rgar( $entry, '1' ),
    'email' => rgar( $entry, '2' ),
    'id' => $gid,
    );
$json = json_encode($body);

print_r($json);
```

Once I submit, the I can see the output results the id as null:

```
{"name":"input_1","email":"example@example.com","id":null}
```

Do I need to assign the global variable to another variable?
I swear I've done this before and I can't remember what needed to be done. It's been a while.

Comment: Do you need to use a global? Is there no other alternative? Perhaps a static variable via a class? Do you have control on how this value is being passed, ie. did you set the global value in the first place?

Comment: @Rasclatt - I'm setting the global variable in another function that is pulling in JSON data from and other source. So yes, I am setting this variable.

Comment: Can you post the other function? from what you have above it doesn't look out of the ordinary.

Comment: This should work, this can't be your real code. Are you sure the variable is even set? And how does the real code looks like?

Comment: With some testing, I believe your problem is that you returned json has no `$json['id_of_json_thing']` or the json is failing and returning empty. If you put a hardcoded value in there like `$gid = 'test';` it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be setting `$gid = null;` outside any function. This could easly be getting reset during program flow. If you need it to start null set it inside your 'things' function

```
global $gid;
$gid = null;
$gid = $json['id_of_json_thing'];
```

And, of course, as Rasclatt said, make sure $json['id_of_json_thing']; is not null itself;